# bubble sort with a boolean to determine whether array is already sorted

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I have following code for bubble sort but its not sorting at all. if I remove my boolean then its working fine. I understand that since my a[0] is lesser than all other elements therefore no swapping is being performed can anybody help me with this.

```
package com.sample;

public class BubleSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 88, 4, 2, 4, 5, 8 };
        a = sortBuble(a);
        for (int i : a) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }

    private static int[] sortBuble(int[] a) {
        boolean swapped = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length && swapped; i++) {
            swapped = false;
            System.out.println("number of iteration" + i);

            for (int j = i+1; j < a.length; j++) {

                if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                    int temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bubble sort is wrong?

```
    private static int[] sortBuble(int[] a) {
        boolean swapped = true;
        int n = a.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n && swapped; i++) {
            swapped = false;
            int newn = 0;
            System.out.println("number of iteration" + i);

            for (int j = 1; j < a.length; j++) {

                if (a[j-1] > a[j]) {
                    int temp = a[j-1];
                    a[j-1] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                    newn = j;
                }
            }
            n = newn;
        }

        return a;
    }
```

Comment: you have written my code in terms of j only but I dont think so its different from my code

Comment: @ankit it is funny to discuss but you described a different process that gets the array sorted but works in a slightly different manner. They are different.

Comment: @SteveP.: do you care to elaborate what is not optimized and how it should be optimized? Updated the answer.

Comment: well, honestly, I don't care that much: bubble sort is an introductory algorithm and one or two heuristics will not make it much better. Asymptotical optimizations do matter and @ankit better move on them. But for the sake of humanity, care to look up the algorithm in your text book (CLRS, Sedgwick work great) or at least at wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the same as yours, but working and more efficient:

```
private static int[] bubblesort(int[] nums)
{
    boolean done = false;

    for (int i = 0;  i < nums.length && !done; i++)
    {
        done = true;

        for (int j = nums.length-1; j > i; j--)
        {
            if (nums[j] < nums[j-1])
            {
                int temp = nums[j];
                nums[j] = nums[j-1];
                nums[j-1] = temp;
                done = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return nums;
}
```

At the end of the i<sup>th</sup> iteration, we know that the first i elements are sorted, so we don't need to look at them anymore.  We need the boolean to determine if we need to continue or not.  If no swaps are made, then we are done.  We can remove the boolean and it will still work, but will be less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It is called flagged bubble sort. It helps to save time mainly. It checks whether the array positions are sorted. if it is sorted it breaks, and move to 2nd execution.

and the code can be rewritten as:-

```
for (int j = 1; j < a.length; j++) {

            if (a[j-1] > a[j]) {
                int temp = a[j-1];
                a[j-1] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
                swapped = true;             
            }
        }
        if(!swapped)
           break;
    }
```